# For what reasons does my text contain black diamonds in this brief code?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I created a file on my localhost with the following code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');

echo "yoá";
```

The output in my Firefox is:

[image]

Why the Unicode replacement character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your PHP script file is not saved as UTF-8 from inside your editor. All decent editors allow you to convert between and save as several different encodings (even Notepad does this now). Save in UTF-8 and you will see the character appear normally.

**Technical explanation**:

The character in question is code point U+00E1 ("latin small letter a with acute"). Supposing that you have saved your script in a single-byte encoding (which is most likely), this character would be represented by the byte with hex value 0xE1, which in binary is

```
11100001
```

From the [UTF-8 encoding rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), we see that this byte falls in the category

```
1110zzzz
```

which is the first of exactly three bytes that encode a single character in the code point range U+0800 to U+FFFF. However, in your case there are either no more bytes following this one or if there are they do not satisfy the UTF-8 encoding restrictions.

Hence, the browser determines that there is a malformed byte sequence and displays the question mark instead.

Comment: I'm using Net Beans on OS X. I tried to find how to save the file as UTF-8 but couldn't find the setting.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't start a project for this one file, just `touch index.php` and then opened it in Net Beans.

Comment: I installed TextMate and used "Open in UTF-8" which showed the replacement character. I replaced it and it now works fine. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 0):

you're sending an utf-8-header but your source-file isn't set to (and saved as) utf-8. check the settings of your code-editor/ide to correct that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'); 
 $txt= "yoá";
 echo iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8",$txt);
```

if you are not sure of if string is valid UTF8 then use lib to test it

```
  http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/

  if(is_valid_utf8($txt)==true)  ....
```

Comment: would you bother to add any description for -ve ?